# TypeScript JSDoc comments not appearing after being exported

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm creating a custom library for this private project ahead. My library structure looks like this:

```
├───lib
│   ├───index.ts
│   └───logging
│       └───log.ts
├───main
│   └───loader.ts
```

index.ts is just a simple loader that looks like so:

```
const fs = require('fs')

let modules = {};
fs.readdirSync(__dirname).filter(file => file != 'index.ts').forEach(dir => {
    fs.readdirSync(`${__dirname}/${dir}`).forEach(file => {
        modules = { ...modules, ...require(`${__dirname}/${dir}/${file}`) };
    })
})

module.exports = modules;
```

log.ts looks like so:

```
const dayjs = require('dayjs')
const {white, black, gray, red, yellow, green, bgRed} = require('chalk')

module.exports.log = {
    /**
    * Logs standard output
    *
    * @type {string} log message.
    */
    print: function (log) {
        let time = dayjs().format('HH:mm');
        log = `${time} - ${log}`;
        console.log(gray(log));
    },
};
```

Now with the entry point of the actual project (main/loader.js) looks like this:

```
const {log} = require('./lib/index.ts')

log.print("Hello, World!")
```

The code runs as expected, it logs "Hello, World!" and everything just fine. Issue being is that JSDoc comments *are not* appearing no matter what I try.
I'm not sure what to do to make them appear.